# Zero out minute/seconds on Date Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, but ultimately I am trying to build a dataset to do a time series forecast. I have a Date column but I want to only capture Year, Month, Day and Hour (ignoring minutes/seconds)

How would I go about doing so? I started by thinking I'd parse out the features I'm after and then just appending a new 'Formatted Date' column by creating a new date. But that's seems to be troublesom (or I'm doing it incorrectly)

Raw Data:

```
              ID                    Date     Primary Type  Year
111434     23810  02/04/2018 01:36:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018
230458     23811  02/05/2018 01:10:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018
300168  11223630  02/03/2018 02:40:00 PM  CRIMINAL DAMAGE  2018
385295     23812  02/06/2018 04:10:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018
484892     23813  02/07/2018 09:23:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018

crime_df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(crime_df['Date']).dt.hour
crime_df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(crime_df['Date']).dt.day
crime_df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(crime_df['Date']).dt.month
print(crime_df.head())

              ID                    Date     Primary Type  Year  Hour  Day  \
111434     23810  02/04/2018 01:36:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018     1    4   
230458     23811  02/05/2018 01:10:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018     1    5   
300168  11223630  02/03/2018 02:40:00 PM  CRIMINAL DAMAGE  2018    14    3   
385295     23812  02/06/2018 04:10:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018     4    6   
484892     23813  02/07/2018 09:23:00 AM         HOMICIDE  2018     9    7   

        Month  
111434      2  
230458      2  
300168      2  
385295      2  
484892      2
```

What's the best approach to creating my new column with the zeroed out minutes/seconds? I tried a couple variations of this thinking it'd do it, but it does not.

```
crime_df['FormattedDate'] = pd.Timestamp((crime_df['Year'], crime_df['Month'], crime_df['Day'], crime_df['Hour']))
```

And then I realized there is probably a way to do it directly from the Date column but I'm not finding much help out there on my friend Google

Comment: I think that gives me the answer!